# how to draw rotated bounding box around the eye in opencv c++

Tags: c++, algorithm, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I am working on a project to detect the eye pair in an image or video, the problem is that how can I draw **rotated bounding box** around the eye pair in opencv c++ while using of some tracking algorithm(Optical flow etc.) to track features.

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct call to draw a rotated rectangle, you have to draw it line by line. You can find example code on how to draw a rotated rectangle [here](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/db/dd6/classcv_1_1RotatedRect.html)

```
Mat image(200, 200, CV_8UC3, Scalar(0));
RotatedRect rRect = RotatedRect(Point2f(100,100), Size2f(100,50), 30);
Point2f vertices[4];
rRect.points(vertices);
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    line(image, vertices[i], vertices[(i+1)%4], Scalar(0,255,0));
```

Comment: This is something to create a box by drawing lines, is this? I used it in my project but not works properly.... :(

Comment: unless you post some code to look at, that's all I can offer

Comment: or maybe this example might help you http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/shapedescriptors/bounding_rotated_ellipses/bounding_rotated_ellipses.html

Comment: no email ... add the relevant code to your question (see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites ).

Comment: Kindly check this link(https://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/examples/face-detection-and-tracking-using-the-klt-algorithm.html) I need this type of type of work to eye tracking it is in matlab I need it in Opencv

Comment: Thanks for your concern :)